# Qt как ввести русский текст в .xls

Tags: qt

Qt как ввести русский текст в .xls (или как в народе говорят excel фаил)

```
QString fname = "win.xls";
QFile file1(fname);
bool status = file1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text);
// если сюда ввести (фаил закрыть) то но просто очистит документ
//    file1.close();
//    file1.open(QIODevice::Append | QIODevice::Text);

if(status)
{
    QTextStream out(&file1);
    // out.setCodec("ANSII");
    out.setCodec("Windows-1251");
  //  out.setCodec("UTF-8");

    out << "Chanel" << "\t" << "U1" << "\t" << "Pa" << "\t" << "Стробы начало"<< "\t" << "Стробы конец"<<"\n";

    for (int k = 0; k<K;k++)
    {
        double U1 = (SREDNIE[k]*obm->stor->per_KV)/obm->stor->Pa/(pow(10,stepen));
        out << k+1 << "\t" << U1 << "\t" <<obm->stor->Pa << "\t" <<select_n0 << "\t"<< select_n1 << "\n";
    }
    file1.close();
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Error save " << fname;
}
```

"Стробы начало","Стробы конец" в файле пишет ?????? ??????  ?????? ????? но английский  прекрасно выводит . что делать помогите . 
Подключенные библиотеки:

```
#include "math.h"
#include <QDateTimeEdit>
#include <QDateTime>
```

Comment: Вам обязательно хранить данные в Windows-1251? Если я не ошибаюсь то знаки вопросов у вас потому, что ваш Юникод не переведен в 1251. Или выберети кодировку UTF-8, или явно перекодируйте информацию в out << ... в 1251

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Для русского текста можно сделать так:

```
out << "Chanel" << "\t" << "U1" << "\t" << "Pa" << "\t" << QString::fromLocal8Bit("Стробы начало")<< "\t" << QString::fromLocal8Bit("Стробы конец")<<"\n";
```

У меня на машине текст успешно сохранился в CP-1251.
Хотя, использовать кириллицу в тексте программы - далеко не лучшая практика, в Qt есть свой механизм интернационализации и локализации.

2) Чтобы Excel открыл файл с разбиением на колонки, лучше сохранять текст в формате CSV https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV
например, так:

```
out << "Chanel" << "," << "U1" << "," << "Pa" << "," << QString::fromLocal8Bit("Стробы начало")<< "," << QString::fromLocal8Bit("Стробы конец")<<"\n";
```

Comment: out.setCodec("Windows-1251");

Comment: я этот код использую на не "ASCII"  это просто попытка кодировок

Comment: 2) Какая кодировка нужна на выходе?

3) В какой кодировке исходный текст программы?

Comment: 2) без разницы лишь бы читал .xls 3) либо UTF-8 , либо windows -1251

Answer (score 0):

Спосибо user2798658 хотя я в общем считай также решил )))

```
        QString  stroka_z1 =  "Стробы начало";
       QString  stroka_z2 = "Стробы конец";

    out << "Chanel" << "\t" << "U1" << "\t" << "Pa" << "\t" << stroka_z1<< "\t" << stroka_z2<<"\n";
```